# Is there a way to get the user who pushed the image to Docker Registry?

Tags: docker, docker-registry

We have a Docker Registry running that uses native basic authentication with nginx, so images can only be pushed to the Registry after authentication. Is it possible to get the user who pushed the image to the Registry?

Answer (score 0):

It's not part of the registry API. You would need to check the logs of that registry and auth server. It's possible the user may self report who they are by setting a label on the image (or the legacy maintainer field), but I wouldn't depend on that for any security critical tasks.

For more on the registry API, see: https://github.com/opencontainers/distribution-spec

Docker also has their API (which predates OCI) documented at: https://docs.docker.com/registry/spec/api/